# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.actions.AttrExtractor

Tags: android, horizontallistview

I am working on project that is migrated from eclipse to Android Studio. When I am building project it shows below error.

```
Execution failed for task ':androidHorizontalListView:mockableAndroidJar'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.utils.FileCache$FileCreatorException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
```

Please help in this.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try to Update Package Downloads.

But First, Set your Updates Channel to `dev`, It will prompt you to download updates. After downloads are finished The Error must go away.

And Finally you can turn the Update Channels back to `Stable` again